# aws DynamoDB pricing, how to understand WCU

Tags: amazon-web-services

Completely new to Aws DynamoDB. After reading the documentation, I am still confused about the WCU and how it impacts cost.

Suppose I want to load 100G of data into DyanmoDB, and each data record is around 2-3 kb. With standard table class, the WCU is $0.00065 per WCU per hour, and 1 WCU writes 1 KB in size.

How to calculate my cost? How is "per hour" applies to this scenario if this data loading is only a one time thing?

Comment: Note that WCU and RCU relate to Provisioned Capacity and, while they have associated pricing, they relate to the cost of pre-provisioning a certain capacity, not to the per request costs. The alternative to Provisioned Capacity is On-Demand. This is quite a complicated topic and if 100GB is genuinely the amount of data you're working with then I'd suggest that you get help from someone with deep DynamoDB knowledge (perhaps even from AWS directly) to a) optimize costs and b) ensure sensible performance for both ingestion and subsequent workloads.

Comment: Also, for all things DynamoDB I can highly recommend [Alex DeBrie](https://www.alexdebrie.com/) and StackOverflow answers from [Leeroy Hannigan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7909676/leeroy-hannigan) and others in the [AWS Collective](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/aws).